# Finding multiple occurrences of a word and printing out the entire line in which the word exists using c-sharp

Tags: c#, .net, string

Hey guys this is something I am trying to do for a while...
So I have a text file online which can be accessed through a link like this `https://example.com/myfile.txt`
the text file contains a few sentences, here are a few

```
This is a sentence
sentences are a combination of multiple words
we cannot imagine a world without sentences
words together form a sentence
here's a sentence orange is a fruit and I love it!
how's the day today?
```

Okay that was all random sentences in the text file, so now If I enter the word 'words' in the input `(string input)` I want it to print out all the lines which contain the input, here's an example

```
sentences are a combination of multiple words
words together form a sentence
```

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. What part of that causes you problems?

Comment: I had trouble doing it and I did not know how to approach it, now I have clarity and a working code to learn and understand thanks to Poul Bak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an obvious case to use `Regex`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpression;

string text = @"This is a sentence
sentences are a combination of multiple words
we cannot imagine a world without sentences
words together form a sentence
here's a sentence orange is a fruit and I love it!
how's the day today?";

string input = "words";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*" + input + @".*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.value);
}
```

**Explanation:** `@"^.*" + input + @".*$", RegexOptions.Multiline`:

`^.*` match zero or more characters from start of line

`input`  match the string in `input` string

`.*$` match zero or more characters at end of line

`RegexOptions.Multiline` makes `^` and `$` match start and end of line (normally they match start and end of whole text).

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, was really looking forward to a good solution and you got me one at last!

Comment: Thanks, man, it fixed my issue, I would love to get you a coffee

Comment: `input` needs to be sanitized. It could contain any regex characters. Use [`Regex.Escape(input)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @PoulBak true, you want to capture the whole line, I didn't get it at first reading

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I did not mean to, it was my brother, sorry!

Answer (score -2):

So, just for the fun of it, you can use these functions (they do what you asked, and the second one allows you to pass the URI so it will download the text file from a web address and proceed with the search.

```
public static global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> SearchFor(string[] Lines, string Term)
{
    global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> r = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(Lines.Length);
    foreach (string l in Lines) { if (l.Contains(Term)) { r.Add(l.Trim()); } }
    r.TrimExcess();
    return r;
}

public static global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> SearchFor(string Text, string Term, bool TextIsUri = false)
{
    if (TextIsUri) { using (global::System.Net.WebClient w = new global::System.Net.WebClient()) { Text = w.DownloadString(new global::System.Uri(Text)); } }
    return SearchFor(Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, global::System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), Term);
}
```

Surelly you can also provide some safety measures like testing if string is empty and such, but i left it without it so you can see the simplest code and improve on it.

Comment: not download, read-only, so every time the program needs to check for stuff the web needs to be available, if not it's not going to work

Comment: no problem either, again it's just an alternative, but if you call "SearchFor("http://example.com/mytext.txt", "word", true)" would access the web, get the file in memory and apply the filter, if called "SearchFor("word bla, of bla bla word word", "word", false)" it will filter the text directly, not getting it from anywhere, using the "Text" argument as the content to filter (could also change it easly to get from a file path instead).